# What's the value of this inductor?

Tags: identification

It seems this inductor got a little hot, since it grew this little bubbles.
I can't measure inductance, but I guess that part is dead anyway.

However, I have trouble reading the value. The rings seem to be Yellow - Grey - Orange - Orange. Could  be 48mH 4%,though many tables do not list orange as 1000µH, neither as tolerance. I'm also confused about this having four color rings.

[image]

Finally, this is part of a power supply circuit based on a LNK304. The datasheet of that IC shows the following sample circuit, which totally matches my board - except there's L2=1mH.

[image]

Maybe, someone with a bit more experience with inductors has an Idea about the value?

Comment: I suspect the heat has messed up the colours. The right hand band is probably gold for 5% tolerance.

Comment: @Finbarr the colors are not messed up. The left two are the same color, but gold as the secobd (last) makes no sense. But that Inductor grows that three yellow bubbles, which are not found anywhere else, and make he think it's dead.

Comment: (Inserting a piece of fibreglass fleece to delay the capacitors' early death is a curious measure compared to mounting the device getting hot with longer leads to where it doesn't directly heat the capacitors that much and air can circulate more freely. Can't imagine the stray inductance to hurt…)

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely it was 1mH and the colors have changed from overheating, just as @Finbarr said. It is certainly not 48mH or 4%, let alone both.

If it has burned out (open), most likely at least the LNK304 is bad as the root cause. If it was relatively low resistance the circuit would still function.